# How can I decode the base64 payload from Google Secret Manager?

Tags: google-secret-manager, google-workflows

When using secret manager, the response is **base64 encoded**. How would one go about decoding it?

```
sendGridSend: 
   steps:    
   - getSecret:    
       call: http.get    
       args:    
           url: ${"https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER") + "/secrets/" + secret + "/versions/latest:access"}    
           auth:    
               type: OAuth2    
       result: secretBase64Payload
```

Comment: @Samuel Liew the question was OK, it should be left open.

Comment: @Pentium10 No, I don't think so. Feel free to post a dispute on [meta] or discuss it in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be like the below snippet, by using `base64.decode`.
As this product just got out of alpha, there is no yet a documentation page linking to the available functions.

```
sendGridSend: 
   params: [secret, from, to, subject, content, contentType]    
   steps:    
   - getSecret:    
       call: http.get    
       args:    
           url: ${"https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER") + "/secrets/" + secret + "/versions/latest:access"}    
           auth:    
               type: OAuth2    
       result: sendGridKey    
   - decodeSecrets:    
       assign:    
       - decodedKey: ${text.decode(base64.decode(sendGridKey.body.payload.data))}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a list of supported functions?

Comment: That's something I forwarded to the relevant people. Hopefully they will create it.